# AJAX post request not being processed in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a "Like" feature on my laravel site. It works fine as a POST request, however I'd like to use AJAX for the request as to not have to reload the page. I gave it an attempt, however I haven't done much AJAX in the past, and I'm getting some errors.

**Markup:**

```
<li data-value="{{$status->id}}" class="like">
  Like
</li>
```

**Laravel route:**

```
Route::get('/status/{statusId}/like', [
    'uses' => '\CommendMe\Http\Controllers\StatusController@getLike',
    'as' => 'status.like',  
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

**JS:**

```
$('.like').click(function() {
 $likeValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
 $token     = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content");
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host + '/status/' + $likeValue + '/like',
    data: {likeValue: $likeValue, _token:$token},
 }).success(function (res){

 });
});
```

This will return the error:

> TypeError: $.ajax(...).success is not a function

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see why this wasn't working. My route was expecting a GET request, not a POST. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host + '/status/' + $likeValue + '/like',
    data: {likeValue: $likeValue, _token:$token},
    success: function(res) {

    }
 });
```